# Apache htaccess setting default index.html or <folder name>.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have an automated legacy system that provides zip files with html content (including images and other files). The system will either provide a folder with an index file or a file with the name as the folder.

For example say the file being sent in was **User Supplies.zip**

We would either see a folder structure like this

**User Supplies/index.html**

or like this

**User Supplies/User Supplies.html**

Currently we examine the contents for the zip file and rename anything that matches the folder name back to index.html. Since there could be other html files in there it has become a bit of spaghetti code to get it to work.

We could get rid of all this code if we can include something to the equivalent of "Use index.html or [folder name].html as the default file"